# Change file permission in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have mistakenly changed the permission of etc folder using command `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/` . How can i revoke this change or set the permission to root accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

sudo chmod 700 -R /etc/

It will set it to root